# Keeping interface elements consistent between 3.5" and 4" screens

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, interface-builder, screen-size

When i have a 4 inch screen size, there is a lot of space for the buttons and labels:

[image]

but when I scale it down to 3.5 inches, the labels under the bottom line of buttons jump above the buttons. There is space for the labels:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it? Is there some other and better way to make a homescreen? Is there any way to put elements on the different screens with a permanent position?
A last question: Do you know of some tuts about designing apps and implement it in xcode, and that it works on the devices!

Comment: noone? is it a trick to make objects have the same position on every device?

Comment: I'd suggest watching the WWDC 2012 session about Auto Layout.

Comment: I will check it out, and every tricks will help

Comment: There are lots of nit-picky rules about Auto Layout but if you watch the vid and go back to your code you will see how to lay it out so that it works for both screens.

Comment: Aaah, i really dont get it! When the screen gets from 4" to 3,5" it push the bottom up! It there any ways to make buttons bigger on 4" and auto- smaller on 3,5"? Or is it tuts on working with many devices?